# Mixing Ruby code and literal markup with Haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

How to write this ERB in HAML

```
<%= some_ruby_code %>:
# OR
<%= some_ruby_code %><br />
```

I can:

```
=some_ruby_code + ":"
# and
=some_ruby_code
%br
```

but I don't want concatenating here and I want to write it inline:

```
(=some_ruby_code):
# and
(=some_ruby_code)%br
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
=some_ruby_code + ":"
-# and
=some_ruby_code + "<br/>"
```

**EDIT 1:**

I'm not sure exactly what you are looking for.  Would you like one of these?

```
==#{some_ruby_code}:
-# and
==#{some_ruby_code}<br/>
```

or

```
==#{some_ruby_code}:
-# and
=some_ruby_code
%br
```

There is no way to use `%br` in HAML unless it is the first non-whitespace thing on the line, as far as I know.

Comment: in first line you're using concatenating and instead of tag I want to use haml `%br`

Comment: What should I do if I want the ruby code to follow the inline text?  Maybe something like the following `some inline text #{som_ruby_code}`

Comment: kalu, yeah, but just be sure to start the line with `==`

Answer (score 9):

Try something like

```
= some_ruby_code
:

= some_ruby_code
%br
```

Note that even though the colon is on a newline, it isn't put into a newline in the HTML.

Or,

```
#{some_ruby_code}:
#{some_ruby_code}
%br
```

HAML can do inline Ruby interpolation with #{}.